# Understanding a conference reviewer comment

Tags: paper-review, conferences

I submitted my first paper to ICALP 2021 and just got the reviews back after receiving a rejection a couple of days ago. The reviews were overall positive with nearly all of the comments on presentation and typos.

Remarkably, two of the reviewers said -- "The ideas in this paper would make a nice chapter for a textbook". I have never seen this comment before and I am trying to understand if this is some sort of shade about the technical contribution or not. Does anyone have any input on what is this supposed to mean?

Comment: Knowing absolutely nothing about your paper, nor the rest of the comments, I would gander a guess that it means the results are presented in an easy to follow, constructive manner, and serve well to teach the topic at hand, but do not push the frontier of knowledge in a significant way.

Comment: I would guess the same. If appropriate, such results are welcome at SOSA: https://www.siam.org/conferences/cm/conference/sosa22